# Manipulating the standard output stream to print multiline strings horizontally

Tags: c++, cout

So I have three strings and these strings are supposed to occupy 3 lines. I thought this was a good way to represent my string:

```
std::string str1 = "███████\n███1███\n███████";
std::string str2 = "███████\n███2███\n███████";
std::string str3 = "███████\n███3███\n███████";
```

But I realise that when I do this and just cout the strings, they get printed on top of each other which is not I want. I want the output to look like this:

```
█████████████████████
███1██████2██████3███
█████████████████████
```

How can I achieve this effect? I only know setw to manipulate the output however I don't know how that could help here.

note: I will have these stored in an array and than loop over the array and print them, I feel like that might change the solution a bit as well.

Comment: There is no easy way. You need to process your strings at the same time. Find the location of the first `'\n'` in each string. Print those partial strings as the first line. Then repeat until with the next `'\n'` until you've exhausted all your strings' content. That is assuming you can't just hard code the whole thing as a single string literal.

Comment: Wow really? thats gonna make my job insanely hard.

Comment: It isn't clear why you are trying to do this. Depending on your actual goal, there may be other solutions. For example a frame buffer of sorts, an array to which you can set characters are various positions which is then processed as a `cout` compatible string.

Comment: If you initialize each one of these as an array of three strings, you can write `[0]` from each, then newline, then `[1]` from each, then newline, then `[2]` of each.  No sense in writing a parser when you control the source.

Comment: I have a card object that has a 5x5 array which contains a pointer to another object which has a function that returns a string just like this. All strings are a square just like that, and when I print and only break after every row I get a picture basically.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hmm that might actually work if I make three functions that return top mid and bottom strings

Answer (score 1):

Store the rows of each card as elements in an array.  That makes it pretty easy.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char * str1[3] = {"███████","███1███","███████"};
    const char * str2[3] = {"███████","███2███","███████"};
    const char * str3[3] = {"███████","███3███","███████"};

    for( int row = 0; row < 3; row ++ )
    {
        std::cout << str1[row] << str2[row] << str3[row] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
█████████████████████
███1██████2██████3███
█████████████████████
```

Again, pretty easy to add a space between those, if you want.

Comment: Oh wow that is actually way easier than I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split each on `\n` and print them. We can use `std::stringstream` for splitting by `\n`.

```
void print(std::array<std::string, 3>& arr){
    std::vector<std::stringstream> arr_buf{};
    arr_buf.reserve(arr.size());

    for(auto& str: arr){
        arr_buf.emplace_back(str);
    }

    for(auto i=0u; i < arr.size(); ++i){
        for(auto& stream: arr_buf){
            std::string t;
            stream >> t;
            std::cout << t ;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
print(arr)

█████████████████████
███1██████2██████3███
█████████████████████
```

[Link to Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c9en64149)

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your output will always be displayed on a modern terminal supporting “[ANSI Escape Codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)” then you can use that to your advantage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


// helper: split a string into a list of views
auto splitv( const std::string & s, const std::string & separators )
{
  std::vector <std::string_view> views;
  std::string::size_type a = 0, b = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    a = s.find_first_not_of( separators, b );
    b = s.find_first_of    ( separators, a );
    if (a >= s.size()) break;
    if (b == s.npos) b = s.size();
    views.emplace_back( &(s[a]), b-a );
  }
  return views;
}


std::string print( const std::string & s )
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  for (auto sv : splitv( s, "\n" ))
    os
      << "\033" "7" // DEC save cursor position
      << sv
      << "\033" "8" // DEC restore cursor position
      << "\033[B";  // move cursor one line down
  return os.str().substr( 0, os.str().size()-5 );
}


std::string movexy( int dx, int dy )
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  if      (dy < 0) os << "\033[" << -dy << "A";
  else if (dy > 0) os << "\033[" <<  dy << "B";
  if      (dx > 0) os << "\033[" <<  dx << "C";
  else if (dx < 0) os << "\033[" << -dx << "D";
  return os.str();
}


int main()
{
  std::string str1 = "███████\n███1███\n███████";
  std::string str2 = "███████\n███2███\n███████";
  std::string str3 = "███████\n███3███\n███████";
  
  std::cout 
    << "\n" "\n\n"  // blank line at top +  blocks are three lines high
    << movexy( 2, -2 ) << print( str1 )  // first block is placed two spaces from left edge
    << movexy( 1, -2 ) << print( str2 )  // remaining blocks are placed one space apart
    << movexy( 1, -2 ) << print( str3 )
    << "\n\n";      // newline after last block, plus extra blank line at bottom
}
```

This produces the output:

```
  ███████ ███████ ███████
  ███1███ ███2███ ███3███
  ███████ ███████ ███████
```

The addition of spacing is, of course, entirely optional and only added for demonstrative purposes.

#### Advantages: UTF-8 and Pretty colors!

The advantage to this method is that you do not have to store or otherwise take any special care for strings containing multi-byte characters (UTF-8, as yours does) ***or any additional information like terminal color sequences***.

That is, you could color each of your blocks differently by adding a color sequence to each `strN` variable! (The caveat is that you must repeat a color sequence after every newline. [This is a known problem with various terminals...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740460/ansi-escape-code-weird-behavior-at-end-of-line))

```
  // red, white, and blue
  std::string str1 = "\033[31m███████\n\033[31m███1███\n\033[31m███████";
  std::string str2 = "\033[37m███████\n\033[37m███2███\n\033[37m███████";
  std::string str3 = "\033[34m███████\n\033[34m███3███\n\033[34m███████";
```

#### Relative vs Absolute Caret Positioning

The other caveat to this *particular* example is that you must be aware of where the text caret (“cursor”) ends-up after each output. You could also use terminal escape sequences to absolutely position the caret before every output.

```
std::string gotoxy( int x, int y )
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << "\033[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
  return os.str();
}
```

Then you wouldn’t have to care where the caret ends up. Just specify an absolute position before printing. Just don’t let the text scroll!

#### Windows OS Considerations

Finally, if you are on Windows and using the old Windows Console, you ***must*** initialize the terminal for ANSI terminal sequences *and* for UTF-8 output:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>

  void init_terminal()
  {
    DWORD mode;
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    GetConsoleMode( hStdOut, &mode );
    SetConsoleMode( hStdOut, mode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING );
    SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 );
  }
#else
  void init_terminal() { }
#endif

int main()
{
  init_terminal();
  ...
```

This does no harm to the new Windows Terminal. I recommend you do it either way just because you do not know which of the two your user will use to run your program, alas.