I Have a problem printing Wide characters and emojis in my snake ladder Game
i am a new cs student i learned c and now i tried to make a snake ladder game decided to use some emojis with Unicode in windows CMD, i don't know where it went wrong and i tried a lot of thing nothing worked, the output is this:
                     none
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     |  |51|51|51|51|51|51|51|51|51|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     | 41| 42| 43| 44| 45| 46| 47| 48| 49| 50|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     |41|41|41|41|41|41|341|341|41|41|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     | 31| �32| CurrentControlSet\C333| 34| 35| 36| 
                     37| 38| a39| a40|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     |31|(31|31|31|31|31|31|31| 


                     331|<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO331|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     | YZ{|}~�221| 
                     �������������������222| 
                     ��������������23| 
                      %&'()*+,-./01234567224| abcdefghijklmnopqrs225| 
                     �����������������226| 
                     �������������������227| a28| 29| 
                     30|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     |t21|e21|21|21|21|021|21|(21|21|21|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     | e11| 12| z13| z14| z15| @16| z17| z18| ;19| z20|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     |�@11|11|11|;11|;11|a11|11|z11|z11|e11|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                     | e01| 02| 03| 04| 05| 06| e3\Users\Adminira007| 
                     dder Game\bk08| e09| 10|
                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

instead of this:
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| | 99| 98| 97| 96| 95| 94| 93| 92| 91|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 81| 82| 83| 84| 85| 86| 87| 88| 89| 90|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 80| 79| 78| 77| 76| 75| 74| 73| 72| 71|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 61| 62| 63| 64| 65| 66| 67| 68| 69| 70|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 60| 59| 58| 57| 56| 55| 54| 53| 52| 51|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 41| 42| 43| 44| 45| 46| 47| 48| 49| 50|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 40| 39| 38| 37| 36| 35| 34| 33| 32| 31|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 21| 22| 23| 22| 23| 26| 27| 28| 29| 30|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 20| 19| 18| 15| 16| 15| 14| 13| 12| 11|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 01| 02| 03| 04| 05| 06| 07| 08| 09| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//here is the code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
typedef struct {
    wchar_t tab[3][20];
}boardchar;
int resetboard(boardchar board[][10]){
    wchar_t reset[] = L" ";
    wcscpy(board[0][0].tab[0], reset);
    wcscpy(board[0][0].tab[0], reset);
    wcscpy(board[0][0].tab[0], reset);
    wchar_t snake[] = L"";
    int index = 1;
    int first;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--){
        if((i % 2) == 0){
            for (int j = 9; j >= 0; j--){
                first = index % 10;
                swprintf(board[i][j].tab[2],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", first);
                swprintf(board[i][j].tab[1],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", ((index - first)/10));
                board[0][0].tab[0][0] = L' ';
                if (index == 100){
                    swprintf(board[i][j].tab[1],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", 0);
                    swprintf(board[i][j].tab[0],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", 1);
                index++;}
            }
        }
        else{
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                first = index % 10;
                swprintf(board[i][j].tab[2],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", first);
                swprintf(board[i][j].tab[1],sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]) / sizeof(*board[i][j].tab[1]), L"%d", ((index - first)/10));
                board[i][j].tab[0][0] = L' ';
                index++;
            }
        }
        board[0][0].tab[2][0] = L' ';
        wcscpy(board[0][0].tab[1], snake);
        board[0][0].tab[0][0] = L' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
int printboard(boardchar board[][10]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("\t\t\t\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n\t\t\t\t|");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            wprintf(L"%s%s%s|", board[i][j].tab[0], board[i][j].tab[1], board[i][j].tab[2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\t\t\t\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n");
    return 0;
}
 int main(void){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    system("chcp 65001 >nul 2>nul");
    boardchar board[10][10];
    resetboard(board);
    printboard(board);
    return 0;
}


cmd doesn't really do unicode.  You can add _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT) to your code to make wcout work better, but the font in cmd still has to have the character you are putting out.

if i try to printf the snake unicode alone it will print fine, i think the problem in my code

You must initialize the Windows Console to handle the output correctly.
(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/72139581/2706707)
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>

  void init_terminal(void)
  {
    DWORD mode;
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    GetConsoleMode( hStdOut, &mode );
    SetConsoleMode( hStdOut, mode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING );
    SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 );
  }
#else
  void init_terminal(void) { }
#endif

int main(void)
{
  init_terminal();
  ...

This initialization makes UTF-8 Unicode output and terminal color sequences work regardless of the user’s choice between Windows Console and Windows Terminal.
There are plenty of other good things you should do with the Windows Console (or Windows Terminal) to set it up to do nice stuff, such as switch to the auxiliary buffer when your program starts and return to the normal buffer when it terminates, etc. You can read all about Windows console/terminal handling here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

i read somewhere about this one, unfortunately tho this is not the solution in my case, i think the problem is in my code.

i figured it out: the problem was that i didn't initialize the board arrays + idk why but the Unicode cannot be displayed with wide chars i removed them and used normal chars and it worked!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char tab[3][20];
}boardchar;
int resetboard(boardchar board[][10]) {
    char reset[] = " ";
    char snake[] = "";
    int index = 1;
    int first;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            for (int j = 9; j >= 0; j--) {
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[0], reset);
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[1], reset);
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[2], reset);
                first = index % 10;
                snprintf(board[i][j].tab[2], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", first);
                snprintf(board[i][j].tab[1], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", ((index - first) / 10));
                board[0][0].tab[0][0] = ' '; // Use narrow character
                if (index == 100) {
                    snprintf(board[i][j].tab[1], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", 0);
                    snprintf(board[i][j].tab[0], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", 1);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[0], reset);
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[1], reset);
                strcpy(board[i][j].tab[2], reset);
                first = index % 10;
                snprintf(board[i][j].tab[2], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", first);
                snprintf(board[i][j].tab[1], sizeof(board[i][j].tab[1]), "%d", ((index - first) / 10));
                board[i][j].tab[0][0] = ' ';
                index++;
            }
        }
        strcpy(board[0][0].tab[2], " ");
        strcpy(board[0][0].tab[1], snake);
        strcpy(board[0][0].tab[0], "");
    }

    return 0;
}
int printboard(boardchar board[][10]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("\t\t\t\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n\t\t\t\t|");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            printf("%s%s%s|", board[i][j].tab[0], board[i][j].tab[1], board[i][j].tab[2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\t\t\t\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n");
    printf("\n***********************************************************************************************************************\n");
    return 0;
}
int main(void){
    system("chcp 65001 >nul 2>nul");
    boardchar board[10][10];
    resetboard(board);
    printboard(board);
    return 0;
}


The difference is that wchar_t is UTF-16, which will not work with printf() and friends. Glad you figured it out!

i never used printf() to print  a wide character but thanks

@HaiTzZ  snprintf is a printf function and doesn't work with wchar_t.
